C# OpenXML LeafElement InnerXml can only be set to null or to an empty string
I am using the OpenXML .NET Library to work on a WordprocessingML document. I need to replace/set the text for a <t> element, but when I do it like this: Element.InnerXml = value i get this error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'This OpenXmlLeafElement's InnerXml can only be set to null or to an empty string.'. I looked into the documentation, but it seems incomplete and does not mention this error. This behaviour is unique to some of the leaf nodes (for now I only found it with Text/<t>), as I can set the parent InnerXml without an issue.
Currently I use a workaround where I replace the parent InnerXml, but seems very hacky to me (and will fail in some cases)
var Parent = Element.Parent ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Leaf node without parent!");
int childIndex = Parent.ChildElements.Select((elem, i) => (elem, i)).First((e) => e.elem == Element).i;
Parent.InnerXml = Parent.InnerXml.Replace(">" + Element.InnerXml + "<", ">" + value + "<");
Element = Parent.ChildElements[childIndex];

I have also tried/considered:

Similar workaround using the Element.OuterXml property in the replace (still not very nice and also adds weird namespace attributes that break the document)
Cloning the child, editing the content and then replacing the child (doesn't work, still cannot set the InnerXml)
Removing the child and creating a new element (the code should work with any LeafElement type -> added complexity)
InnerText is protected (even though in the docs imply it can be used to set text)

I might just be missing somethign in the docs, but I feel like there ought to be an easy way to set the text of a text element...

Just a thought: a <w:t> element is an OpenXmlLeafTextElement, and that element type  has a .Text property which you may be able to set - perhaps you have to do some kind of cast on your Element variable. I get the impression that the OpenXmlLeafElement (and OpenXmlLeafTextElement) class throws that exception because it's trying to discourage attempts to insert "text" the contains child elements which shouldn't be allowed in a "leaf" node.

@jonsson that is a good point. I wanted to get an implementation that is completely independent of the type of node that is being dealt with, although im starting to believe the only way to do that is with those weird workarounds. I get the reasoning of not wanting the innerxml to be filled with a child elem, however it would have been nice to mb only throw that exception in the setter when there is actual xml inserted (or allow direct access to the innertext for all leaf nodes that have text). I will consider my options, thank you for your thoughts! :)

I suspected as much. Unfortunately I can't make any good suggestions as I don't know enough about what is feasible in C#/OfficeOpenXMLSDK - at a certain point, it's a question of what makes the decision about how to modify the text. Could be worth coming up with your next "best effort" and posting a new question to see if anyone can improve on that. (Or maybe even try the Stack Exchange Code Review site).
